# How to debug an Angular/Java/Spring application that uses Keycloak?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, keycloak

I built a simple application that uses keycloack for user authentication. However, I would like to make some of the routes public. Something like `localhots:4200/public-route`

I tried removing `canActivate` from the route declaration, but it didn't do much good. When I put `localhots:4200/public-route` in the browser, it keeps redirecting to the login screen. Is there any way to debug the authentication process to "force" validation for a specific route?

Comment: which keycloak adapter are you using?

Answer (score 0):

how about letting canActivate return true ?